# Settimeout in Vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to alert every 5 seconds. Tried this without any luck.

```
function getir()

msgbox("Working...")

End function


dim ba
ba = setTimeOut(getir(),5000)
```

What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: Alert for 5 sec: `BtnCode = WshShell.Popup("Working...", 5, "Alert", 0 + 48)` and WshShell must be defined `Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`. Or wait 5 sec by `WScript.Sleep 5000`

Comment: Hey thanks, but I dont need popup or message. Thats cheating :) That msgbox was just an example. I have other things inside there.

Comment: Stop being vague then. @JosefZ was helping withing the scope of the question you asked. You asked for an alert every 5 seconds which is what his comment would provide. If you are looking for something else then please be explicit. You will get a better answer faster